# Famous graphs with nice 3D embeddings

Tags: graph-theory, 3d

The Petersen graph has an interesting 3D embedding.  Take a tetrahedron. Add a midpoint to each edge. Connect opposing midpoints for a Petersen graph.

The Perkel graph or [57-cell](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/The57Cell/) has an interesting 3D embedding that starts with a dodecahedron. The [Grünbaum graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GruenbaumGraphs.html) also starts with a dodecahedron. The dual to the [Klein quartic graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KleinQuartic.html) has a nice embedding. The various famous polyhedra and polytopes all have corresponding graphs.

The [Clebsch graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClebschGraph.html) can be made by adding diagonals between farthest-apart vertices of a 3D tesseract.

What other famous graphs have interesting 3D embeddings?